# How do I pay off a car in my fathers and my name to get the credit?

Tags: car

if my father is the primary signer on my car and I want to pay off the loan as the primary signer, How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to have the payment history reflect positively on your credit report?

Comment: And are you asking to continue to make payments, over the next few years? (i.e. You can edit question to help clarify your intent.)

Comment: Are you also a signer on your car?  Have you checked your credit report to determine whether or not the car loan appears?

Comment: Can you explain the question better?  No-one seems to understand quite what you're asking at the moment.  I assume the intended answer is *not* "learn to fake your father's signature".

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can pay off a loan, just send a check with the loan account number in the memo field. Title (ownership) is different: after the car is paid off ask dad to sign the title over to you.

Comment: You may be 100% correct, but I read the question to ask how to transfer to her name and pay it off, over the time left on the loan, not tomorrow, in full.